# Exercise and stretches to help me reach my feet

Tags: exercise, feet, stretching, hips

I used to be very fit, but my lifestyle has slowly become more sedentary so that I am now overweight and very inflexible

Because of this I am having more and more difficulty reaching my feet to put shoes and socks on and off, and to wash them and keep my nails trimmed

What I need is a regime of stretches that will make me more supple and flexible, so that I can "touch my toes" with improved ease

I would have thought the primary joints involved in this would be my hips, but I'm open to any suggestions

Is there anyone who can advise me?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about physiotherapists, but one solution that is over thousand years old is [Surya Namaskar, or Sun Salutations](http://www.artofliving.org/yoga/yoga-poses/sun-salutation).

One rep = two sets of yoga poses that give you a total body workout.

[image]

If you are someone who doesn't like to exercise, or is short on time, Surya Namaskar is definitely for you.

Recommended daily is 54 reps = 108 sets (according to Hindu numerology)

Gradually build up your endurance and stamina. I am currently at 33 reps and I notice improved flexibility and strength.

#### Correction

One set is the 12 yoga poses that work both sides of the body.

Aim for 108 sets of 12. As of Aug 2016 I am on 72 sets of 12.

Comment: "One rep = two sets" because you usually do both a right-version and a left-version of the pose. So on your even sets, read 'left' on steps (4) and (9) instead of 'right'.

Answer (score 0):

I used to only be able to touch my knees. Within 2-3 months I learned how to touch my feet. I did this by two simple stretching exercises, but I made sure to do them regularly. The main trick was to build it into my daily-routine:

- I started stretching in the shower, simply bending forward.
- I started stretching before going to sleep, doing this:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-wiOqYcxoI

It only take me 2 minutes every day.